# what's wrong with my formula?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm making a function which returns the body fat composition from below algorithm:

```
495/(1.0324-0.19077(LOG(waist-neck))+0.15456(LOG(height)))-450 // for men

495/(1.29579-0.35004(LOG(waist+hip-neck))+0.22100(LOG(height)))-450 // for women
```

I convert it into java language as below:

```
495/((1.0324f-(0.19077f*(Math.log(_waist-_neck)))+0.15456f*(Math.log(_height))))-450 // for men
```

and the values are:

```
_height = 70.86f; // 180cm & 70in
_waist = 35.43f; // 90cm & 35in
_neck = 19.68f; // 50cm & 19in
// values are converted from centimeter
```

in my way, it returns **-25.125** But in http://www.calculator.net/body-fat-calculator.html site, which already is using this algorithm (see below the converter),  I put theses values it returns **10.3**

what is my wrong? is there any thing lost in my nested formula??

Comment: Log of which base is in mentioned equation?

Comment: The `()` pairs from the formular are diferent in your code.

Comment: The formula doesn't seem to indicate which unit should be used also

Comment: Did you enter the numbers in a suitable order? let the program show you intermediate values, too.

Comment: @vib please visit the website I provied

Comment: @greybeard , I put the order as the numeric version top of the answer, look please

Comment: @user3840019 I did, it's not 100% clear for me what unit they use, anyway, try the other first two suggestions first

Comment: @DaveSexton does it matter?

Comment: @vib they are using INCHEs

Comment: @Thomas the (hip) value is for women only, my formula is based on men body.

Comment: @Thomas in the formula, (hip) not mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula expects the input in centimeters, not inches, and uses base-10 logarithm:

```
@Test
public void formula() throws Exception
{
    float _height = 180;
    float _waist = 90;
    float _neck = 50;
    double fat = 495/(1.0324f-(0.19077f*(Math.log10(_waist-_neck)))+0.15456f*(Math.log10(_height)))-450;
    System.out.println(fat);
}
```

Output

> 10.31526981020346